# How can I validate empty fields with cypress:

Tags: angular, user-interface, testing, filter, cypress

I already have a method that validate when they have some information on it, but when there is nothing it's crash

```
Cypress.Commands.add('selectedFilterPlan', (filterId, idComponentList) => {
  cy.get(filterId).should('be.visible');
  cy.get(filterId).should('have.value', '');
  cy.get(filterId)
  .then((selects) => {
    let select = selects[0];
    cy.wrap(select).click();
      if(cy.get(idComponentList).should("be.visible")){
        cy.get(idComponentList)
        .get("nz-option-item")
        .then(function(item) {
        cy.wrap(item[0]).click();
        cy.wait(500);
        cy.get("[data-cy=result-filter-list]").should("be.visible");
        });
      }
 });
});
```

_

```
    it('select dropdown plan filters', () => {
      cy.selectedFilterPlan('[data-cy=id-filter-1]', "#cdk-overlay-1");
      cy.selectedFilterPlan('[data-cy=id-filter-2]', "#cdk-overlay-2");
      cy.selectedFilterPlan('[data-cy=id-filter-3]', "#cdk-overlay-3");
      cy.selectedFilterPlan('[data-cy=id-filter-4]', "#cdk-overlay-4");
      cy.selectedFilterPlan('[data-cy=id-filter-5]', "#cdk-overlay-5");
    });
```

I want to create a method that validate and pass to the next field when its empty

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcdfb.png)

Answer (score 0):

in your custom command, you used `cy.get(idComponentList).should("be.visible")` inside if statement, but, should() yields the same subject, in your case, idComponentList. It doesnt return a boolean. in cypress documentation it is clearly stated that cypress is not suitable for conditional testing.

If you really need to check existence of an element you can use: `Cypress.$('your_locator').length` which will return the number of elements present in DOM, i.e.

`if(Cypress.$(idComponentList).length !== 0)`

or for the visibility, you can use Cypress.dom methods:

```
cy.get(idComponentList).then($el => {
  Cypress.dom.isVisible($el) // true if visible
})
```

I hope, it will be useful.